# How to set a variable to current date and date-1 in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, date

I want to set the variable `date-today` to the current date, and `date_dir` to yesterday's date, both in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

I am doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash
d=`date +%y%m%d%H%M%S`
echo $d
```

Comment: I'm confused how you managed to get stuck at the exact point that you did. You managed to retrieve the date using a specified format -- but not the format you want. You managed to save the output to a variable -- but not the variable you want. How did you manage to write the code under "I am doing this", and how come you can't do the little bit of extra work of tweaking it to what you need?

Comment: @ruakh: actually it is not dispalaying the $d variable that is why and i  am very new to this bash scripting

Comment: The script that you've posted *does* print `$d`. What makes you say that it doesn't?

Comment: @ruakh: i have done it. thanks !!! i was missing the "$d"

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can try:

```
#!/bin/bash
d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
echo "$d"
```

EDIT: Changed y to Y for 4 digit date as per QuantumFool's comment.

Comment: Actually, if the year is supposed to appear as four characters long (i.e. 2016), then %Y should be used in place of %y (which will return 16 with the 20 cut off)

Comment: How does THIS solve the OPs question ? The variable $d is not the one he wants and where is the yesterdays-part ?

Answer (score 18):

You can also use the shorter format

From the man page:

```
%F     full date; same as %Y-%m-%d
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
date_today=$(date +%F)
date_dir=$(date +%F -d yesterday)
```

Answer (score 13):

simple:

```
today="$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')"
yesterday="$(date -d yesterday '+%Y-%m-%d')"
```

Answer (score 2):

you should `man date` first

```
date +%Y-%m-%d
date +%Y-%m-%d -d yesterday
```

Comment: i want to set it to a variable how to do that. i am creating a bash script

Comment: i would also like to tell you that it is picking date +%Y-%m-%d `2013-12-09`   date +%Y-%m-%d -d yesterday is picking `2013-12-09`